# Unity Light Probe Coefficients == 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting

I am trying to save light probe data to a file.

However, nothing is `[Serializable]` (LightProbes or ShericalHarmonicsL2) so I am attempting to do it manually)

The problem is that all of my Unity Light Probe Coefficients print as 0?

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
for (int c = 0; c < LightmapSettings.lightProbes.count; c++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                Debug.Log(c + ","+ i + "," + j + " = " + LightmapSettings.lightProbes.bakedProbes[c][i, j]);
            }
        }
    }
```